# Python 3, format print output of a dictionary in several column (like a formated table)

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I want to format my print output like a table. Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

result = b'[{"id":"865776","name":"US 2019","url":"www.abc.com"}, 
{"id":"646829496481089588","name":"MultiDomainDemo","url":"www.n149.mydomain.com 
/o/rw48vavc/manage/organization/overview"},{"id":"549236","name":"Developer 
Sandbox","url":"www.overview"}, 
{"id":"566327653141842188","name":"NetAssoc","url":"www.n6/organization"}]'
response_list = eval(result.decode())
print("id                   name")
print("_________________________")

for n in response_list:

    print (n['id'], " " ,n['name'])
```

the result is like this:

```
id                   name
_________________________
865776   US 2019
646829496481089588   MultiDomainDemo
549236   Developer Sandbox
566327653141842188   NetAssoc
```

but I want it like this:

```
id                   name
_________________________
865776               US 2019
646829496481089588   MultiDomainDemo
549236               Developer Sandbox
566327653141842188   NetAssoc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tabulate` module. And you can also chnage table style using `tablefmt` argument.

```py
from tabulate import tabulate
result = b'[{"id":"865776","name":"US 2019","url":"www.abc.com"}, {"id":"646829496481089588","name":"MultiDomainDemo","url":"www.n149.mydomain.com/o/rw48vavc/manage/organization/overview"},{"id":"549236","name":"Developer Sandbox","url":"www.overview"}, {"id":"566327653141842188","name":"NetAssoc","url":"www.n6/organization"}]'
response_list = eval(result.decode())

header = response_list[0].keys()
rows =  [x.values() for x in response_list]

print(tabulate(rows,  headers=header, tablefmt='grid'))
```

**Output:**

```
+--------------------+-------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
|                 id | name              | url                                                           |
+====================+===================+===============================================================+
|             865776 | US 2019           | www.abc.com                                                   |
+--------------------+-------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| 646829496481089588 | MultiDomainDemo   | www.n149.mydomain.com/o/rw48vavc/manage/organization/overview |
+--------------------+-------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
|             549236 | Developer Sandbox | www.overview                                                  |
+--------------------+-------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| 566327653141842188 | NetAssoc          | www.n6/organization                                           |
+--------------------+-------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
```